Isekai manga about a guy with either infinite mana or a streaming power, who has crazy fans
I'm looking for a manga that is an isekai. I only watched a recap of it on YouTube but I want to read the actual thing.

The MC is a male human

The MC came from another world and died before being transferred

MC has either infinite mana or a streaming power

The world has different races, mainly demons and humans

The MC is a anonymous streamer in the world and has very crazy fans


Things I don't know but think are in it:

I think it's colored but it might not be

The MC is considered a very powerful/informative person



You can accept a correct answer by giving on the check mark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Might it be Isekai de Haishin Katsudou wo Shitara Tairyou no Yandere Shinja wo Umidashiteshimatta Ken?


Living in Ataraxia, a world of swords and magic, a reincarnated individual decided to make a living out of streaming. Living in a world where such a thing did not exist despite the many forms of entertainment, he quickly made a name for himself.
This is not the tale of just a streamer... but of a boy who becomes a legend as a haishinsha.

....

Kanata has a "infinite magical strength" that allowed him to get into this academy despite being a commoner. His body is endowed with an endless amount of magical power, as the phrase "infinite magical power" implies. From the highest, SSS, SS, S, A, and so on, to the bottom, F, are the ranks of magical power. He changed the amount of power he placed into his body when measuring his magical power, and his grade was a S ⬌ SS⬌ SSS. Nevertheless, he also realized that this boundless magical power was a barrier to living quietly.

Found by searching for isekai mana streamer

thank you FuzzyBoots this is it and before you mods try saying "just press the accept button and disappear i like giving thanks

Honestly, usually the issue is more people who give thanks without accepting. :-)
